# Mathematica doesn't solve wave equation when given boundary conditions

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, wave

Still new to Mathematica syntax.  When I do:

```
DSolve[{
  D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == (1/(v*v))*D[u[x, t], {t, 2}],
  u[0, t] == 0,
  u[l, 0] == 0
  }, u, {x, t}]
```

it just returns what I entered

```
DSolve[{(u^(2,0))[x,t]==(u^(0,2))[x,t]/v^2,u[0,t]==0,u[l,0]==0},u,{x,t}]
```

However, when I remove the boundary conditions, I get

```
{{u->Function[{x,t},C[1][t-(Sqrt[v^2] x)/v^2]+C[2][t+(Sqrt[v^2] x)/v^2]]}}
```

with C[1] and C[2] representing the functions for the boundary conditions.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 things:

1. Don't you need more boundary and initial conditions than just 2? You have second order derivatives on left and right side, each requires 2 conditions. Hence total is 4. see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaveEquation1-Dimensional.html
2. I do not think DSolve or NDSolve can solve initial and boundary value problems? I seem to have read this somewhere sometime ago. No time to check now.

Comment: Ah, indeed you are correct.  I had manually solved it using separation of variables, and since I was doing it for a standing wave I forgot that set-up implied initial conditions.

Comment: @Nick: So can Mathematica solve it if you supply initial conditions `u[x,0]==f[x]`??

Comment: No, I am not able to get it to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Mathematica doesn't know how to deal with these boundary conditions for [2nd order PDEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveSecondOrderPDEs.html). How would you want the answer returned? As a general Fourier series?

This is [mentioned in the Mathematica Cookbook](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=BkDxC_O1WisC&lpg=PA533&ots=hjf_IlLEHV&dq=mathematica%20wave%20equation%20boundary%20conditions&pg=PA533#v=onepage&q&f=false) (and probably other places)...

Breaking down the problem for Mathematica (with the dimensional factor `v->1`), you find

```
In[1]:= genSoln = DSolve[D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {t, 2}], u, {x, t}] // First
Out[1]= {u -> Function[{x, t}, C[1][t - x] + C[2][t + x]]}

In[2]:= Solve[u[0, t] == 0 /. genSoln]
Out[2]= {{C[1][t] -> -C[2][t]}}

In[3]:= u[l, 0] == 0 /. genSoln /. C[1][x_] :> -C[2][x] // Simplify
Out[3]= C[2][-l] == C[2][l]
```

that the solution is written as `f(t-x)-f(t+x)` where `f` is periodic over `[-l,l]`...

You can't do any more with out making assumptions about the smoothness of the solution.

You can check that the standard Fourier series approach would work, e.g.

```
In[4]:= f[x_, t_] := Sin[n Pi (t + x)/l] - Sin[n Pi (t - x)/l]

In[5]:= And[D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == D[u[x, t], {t, 2}], 
              u[0, t] == 0, u[l, 0] == 0] /. u -> f // Reduce[#, n] & // Simplify

Out[5]= C[1] \[Element] Integers && (n == 2 C[1] || n == 1 + 2 C[1])
```